# Download, store and update a bunch of pictures on Android App

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm very new on Android, sorry if my question is too obvious.

What I want to do is to create an activity to display a weekly magazine (actually is bunch of jpg pictures - 10 to 20)

This magazine should be downloaded from my server and stored in the app AND updated every week.

How can I do this?

Comment: your server have return link API ?

Comment: Nope... I use 1and1, do you think is possible to have this return link API with this provider?

Comment: if your server have return link API. I will help you.

Comment: What kind of data does your server return ? Does it return just the images, or also html ?

Comment: Server return link API. link API return String Json. From String Json parse to String. From string url of image ussing Picasso Load image to ImageView. From ImageView when click download image and save to Sdcard